# How to remove hebrew niqqud from a string in python?

Tags: python, string, nlp, normalization, hebrew

given a string s, I want a method to return a string s' which contains all of the chars in s except the ones which are hebrew niqqud.
for example: "שָׁלוֹם" will become "שלום".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this method can work:

```
def remove_niqqud_from_string(my_string):
    return ''.join(['' if  1456 <= ord(c) <= 1479 else c for c in my_string])
```

Comment: This doesn't cover cantillations, unfortunately..

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
s = re.sub('[\u0591-\u05C7]+', '', s)
```